# Error when creating a record with Automapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, controller, automapper

I´m using Visual Studio 2019, .NET Core 3.1. I´m trying to create a CRUD using Autoapper. On the create action I am getting an error, I´ve tried several forms but none seems to work.

Error:

```
The entity type 'CustomerCountriesDto' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.
```

On the view:

```cs
@model ManufacturaMVC.Models.CustomerCountries
```

Controller:

```cs
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    
public CustomerCountriesController(ApplicationDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
{
    _context = context;
    _mapper = mapper;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("CustomerCountries")] CustomerCountries customerCountries)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //var model = _mapper.Map<CustomerCountriesDto>(customerCountries);
        var user = _mapper.Map<CustomerCountries, CustomerCountriesDto>(customerCountries);
        _context.Add(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();                
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```

---

Error:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
```

Controller:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("CustomerCountriesDto")] CustomerCountries customerCountries)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var model = _mapper.Map<CustomerCountriesDto>(customerCountries);
        var user = _mapper.Map<CustomerCountriesDto, CustomerCountries>(customerCountries);
        _context.Add(user);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();                
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(customerCountries);          
}
```

View:

```cs
@model ManufacturaMVC.ViewModels.CustomerCountriesDto
```

---

Error:

```
The entity type 'CustomerCountriesDto' was not found
```

View:

```cs
@model ManufacturaMVC.Models.CustomerCountries
```

Controller:

```cs
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("CustomerCountriesDto")] CustomerCountries customerCountries)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var model = _mapper.Map<CustomerCountriesDto>(customerCountries);
        //var user = _mapper.Map<CustomerCountries, CustomerCountriesDto>(customerCountries);
        _context.Add(model);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();                
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(customerCountries);          
}
```

---

Models:

```cs
public class CustomerCountries
{
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Longitud máxima para el país: 50")]
    public string CustomerCountry { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<CustomerRegions> CustomerRegions { get; set; }
}
```

DTO:

```cs
public class CustomerCountriesDto
{
    public string CustomerCountry { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping profile:

```cs
public class AutoMapping : Profile
{
    public AutoMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<CustomerCountries, CustomerCountriesDto>(); 
    }
}
```

DbContext:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    
    }
    
    public DbSet<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerCities> CustomerCities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerCountries> CustomerCountries { get; set; }
    
    // More code ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Categories>().HasKey(m => m.CategoryId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerCities>().HasKey(m => m.CustomerCity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerCountries>().HasKey(m => m.CustomerCountry);
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me how is the correct way or, what is wrong?

Comment: The error clearly is related to EF. You're trying to add a model that's not in any of the DbSet you've configured. I suggest that you read the links inside Prolog's answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62804529/1504480

Comment: I'm glad it helped. just on a side note, I tend to go for the ServiceStack.Text package as it does not need all the mapping setup of AutoMapper, and it has a lot of additional functionality.  github - https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the mapping for the Dto to class, you have class to Dto.

```
public class AutoMapping : Profile
{
    public AutoMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<CustomerCountries, CustomerCountriesDto>(); 
        //add this
        CreateMap<CustomerCountriesDto, CustomerCountries>();
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
Also found that you could add `.ReverseMap()` to the mapping. That should then cover the mapping the other way round.

```
public class AutoMapping : Profile
{
    public AutoMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<CustomerCountries, CustomerCountriesDto>().ReverseMap();       
    }
}
```

Comment: That´s why I´ve found out yesterday! thanks @CobyC, you do have the attitude, no chatty, just a response

Comment: found out today that you could use `.ReverseMap()` to cover the opposite mapping without having to add a `CreateMap<>()`

Answer (score 3):

If you are programming by trial and error, doesn't really know what you are doing or just plainly counting on arranging few lines of code in the right order... it's not the way to go. These are signs that you need to step up your knowledge by reading some documentation, follow tutorials or go way back where things were more understandable. If you fail to do so, you'll be just spending your own time in a very inefficient way growing more frustrated because you don't understand things you deal with. One step at a time! Trial and error technique can rarely lead to good results and even then usually only seem to do so, it's almost never a good solution to complex problems.

Judging from your question you do not only not know what should be mapped, but also what should be added to DbContext. These are the very basics of CRUD, so instead of just giving you the answer on a plate and harming you by doing so, I'll direct you to some readings, after which you should figure it out on your own. I know this is Q&A site, but I just can't this time.

#### Readings:

Creating a CRUD in ASP.NET Core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Adding a new entity to DbContext:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/saving/basic#adding-data](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/saving/basic#adding-data)

Getting started with AutoMapper in ASP.NET Core:

https://code-maze.com/automapper-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

Question - did you register the Profile to the MapperConfiguration? Like:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
   cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapping>();
});
```

Then you can use that in your DI, Ninject example below.

```
Bind<IMapper>().ToMethod(ctx =>
    new Mapper(config, type => ctx.Kernel.Get(type)));
```